# Edge extension requesting JSON doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an Edge extension, and I need to request JSON from an external website. The following example works fine on stackoverflow.com, but fails on steamcommunity.com/id/ where I need it.

Here are the files I have:

jQuery (from local file)

manifest.json:

```
{
  "author": "me",
  "name": "Get JSON",
  "description": "get json",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://steamcommunity.com/id/*",
        "*://stackoverflow.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

myscript.js:

```
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

As I've said, this example works fine on Stackoverflow, but fails on Steam.

This is the error I receive on the Steam website:

```
CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'connect-src 'self' http://steamcommunity.com https://steamcommunity.com https://api.steampowered.com/ http://localhost:27060 http://store.steampowered.com/ https://store.steampowered.com/' in Content-Security-Policy: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json. Resource will be blocked.
```

EDIT: I should also add, that this exact example works fine when using a Chrome extension in Google Chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge, differently from Chrome and Firefox, doesn't ignore the website CSP rules for extensions.

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11320214/ for an open issue.

The only viable workaround I know, which I also tested myself, is to change the CSP response headers on the fly by using `browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`, which luckily is well supported in Edge.

NOTE: this code was adapted from this great article, which also explains the problem in more detail: https://transitory.technology/browser-extensions-and-csp-headers/

The code adds your extension to the allowed urls for each CSP header and directive, it should be executed in the background page, which should be set as `persistent`.

Make sure to add the `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions to your `manifest.json`.

```
const cspHeaderNames = [
  'content-security-policy',
  'content-security-policy-report-only',
  'x-webkit-csp'
];

// @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives
const cspSources = [
  'connect-src',
  'default-src',
  'font-src',
  'frame-src',
  'img-src',
  'media-src',
  'object-src',
  'script-src',
  'style-src',
  'child-src',
  'form-action',
];

const url = browser.extension.getURL("").slice(0, -1); // (remove trailing "/")

browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
  details.responseHeaders.forEach(header => {
    const isCspHeader = cspHeaderNames.indexOf(header.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    if (isCspHeader) {
      let newValue = header.value;
      cspSources.forEach(source => {
        newValue = newValue.replace(source, source + ' ' + url);
      });
      header.value = newValue;
    }
  });
  return {
    responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
  };
}, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
  types: ['main_frame', "sub_frame"],
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```